# Receiving binary data via http request in node js server

Tags: python, node.js, http-post, binary-data

I am trying to receive an image binary data in a node js express app. The data is sent by the following python script:

```
import requests
import shutil
from time import sleep

def uploadFile(url,filename):
    url = 'http://208.97.169.108:3000'
    files = {'photo':open("C:/EmojifyMe/downloadedImage.jpg",'rb')}
    values = {'name':"Ali"}
    unsplashAuthHeader = {"auth":unsplash_id,'acceptversion': 'v1'};
    response = requests.post(url,files=files);
    print(response.text)
    if(response.status_code == 200):
        print("Upload Successful")
```

The HTTP request made by the python script is:

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {
    "photo": "[image binary data comes here]"
  }, 
  "form": {
    "sentby": "Osama Asif"
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "/", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Connection": "close", 
    "auth":"14fe25847dcac2578100192",
    "Content-Length": "273", 
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=59e0880732fd417bbca2fefe900275de", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.18.4"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "103.255.4.58", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

This is what I have done so far at the node JS server while trying to get the attribute "files.photo":

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req, res)
{
  res.writeHead(200);
  console.log("Received");
  console.log(req.body.files.photo);
  res.end("Got it!")
});
app.listen(3000);
console.log("Listening to port 3000");
```

When the request was received, "undefined" was logged at the console.

I'm looking for a method to receive the correct binary data, and also to convert it back to a jpg image.

P.S When I try to access the "auth" attribute of "headers" using req.get("auth"), it works just fine, but this method doesn't work for other attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used base64 encoding at both ends and that worked perfectly for me.